# esp32 adafruit huzza32 touch button

Tags: pins, button

I'm having a problem mapping touch pins(for touch buttons) on adafruit hazzah, because pins on the chip(for touch sensors) and board doesn't match. Does anybody knows how to connect them(to which pins) on the board itself:
 https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-huzzah32-esp32-feather.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf

On page 8 there is a chart, under the "function" colunm it lists which pins are TOUCH and shows the GPIO# for them. TOUCH pins 0 through 9 are listed here. I have noticed that there doesn't seem to be a gpio0 and gpio2 brought out on the feather which are TOUCH1 and TOUCH2(theres probably a reason for it).

Pins on the feather that have touch capability:

A5, 12/A11, 13/A12, 14/A6, 15/A8, 27/A10, 32/A7, 33/A9

I haven't tested it yet but will in a day or so and confirm.

Comment: Please try to put the most important content from the link in your answer (if the link breaks the answer will be partly useless).